# How can I solve the undefined index error?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.6 and I have a problem. I have the following code:

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

$uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

// This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
// built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
// application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```

And get this error:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: REQUEST_URI .

Even, when I run the server via terminal using this `command:php -S localhost:8000`

The following message appears:

> Not Found
>   The requested resource / was not found on this server.

I do not know why this is happening. the route '/' is defined in my web.php

```
<?php

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Web Routes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
    | routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
    | contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
    |
    */
    //Contiene todas las rutas que vamos a trabajar
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
```

Comment: run php  artisan serve

Comment: it worked, I have an error that says Route is not a class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code expects to have this index, but you're running PHP in CLI mode. **REQUEST_URI** variable of **$_SERVER** superglobal is only available if you're reaching script by browser.